# Don't have option to create the jUnit test class

Tags: eclipse, junit

Junit test class option is not listed in eclipse and if I create a normal class and add the @Test annotation it still don't run the test class besides I have imported the junit jar files to my project but still eclipse is not running any test classes, can someone please help?

[image]

furthermore when I hit the other option still there is no option to choose Junit
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using? Which package?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a suite: Choose Other and then choose Java -> Junit -> JUnit Test Suite.

Next page choose between JUnit 3 or 4 and click Finish

You can create Class with JUnit Test by choosing Other and then choose Java -> Junit -> JUnit Test Case.

Comment: I have tried this one too but there is no option for Junit

Comment: @gs650x choose Other and then write in text box junit

Comment: Still no luck :( have added the screenshot too